# Is the latest version of eclipse fully compatible with windows 10?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, compatibility, windows-10

So, I'm finally staring to consider updating my windows 7 PC to windows 10. However, I'd like to make sure that eclipse will continue to work. To be specific, is the latest version of the eclipse IDE for Java developers (64 bit) fully and completely compatible with the Windows 10 OS. Download link:http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/marsr

```
File: eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64.zip.
```

Thanks!

Edit: 
Mostly looking for official confirmation from eclipse website, Microsoft, or oracle. Im also good with confirmation from someone who has personally used eclipse on windows 10. Just want to be sure! Otherwise if I can get enough resources that say it works that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Windows 10 about 3 weeks ago. I don't have an official confirmation from Eclipse or Microsoft, just writing from my own experience.

Eclipse is running fine, as long as you use it. There is just one bad thing that I noticed on Eclipse since I upgraded to Windows 10:
If you let Eclipse with a server running (I use Tomcat v8.0) through the night, the server, also Eclipse become unresponsive to the point that you have to force close both from the Task Manager.

I don't have any more information about this, since I just started searching for this issue, will update my answer for further info after I check the root cause for this.

Comment: Yup okay thanks! I upgraded. Its running fine as far as I can tell. I dont use Tomcat so no issue there! (Just a beginner! No advanced tools for me!) I was just more concerned which crashes, bug splats, slowness, resolution, ect, Also sorry about late response I didn't even notice this untill now.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
After much use of eclipse in Windows 10, I would just like to put this information out there so everyone can see. It works fine, no bugs, no issues except for a minor problem. On high resolution laptop displays the icons become so small on native resolution that they are barely even usable. However, this can be easily fixed by temporarily changing screen resolution to 1920 * 1080.

Comment: Eclipse Mars on Windows 10 is shrinked views...with most of the menu's jumbled -up...will some body plz help me...I have a brand new LAPTOP with updated Drivers ...working for other Applications installed, Also tried Uninstall/Re- install drivers...

Comment: @N.S.Karthik okay I'll try to help you. Do me a favor, can you take a screenshot of eclipse and host it on an image hosting site like imgur? Then send me the link so I can see whats going on.

Comment: URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737347/eclipse-mars-on-windows-10-appearnce-jumbeled-up