# Eclipse Mars on Windows 10 appearance jumbled up

Tags: eclipse

[image]
[image]
Eclipse installed on Brand New DELL Precision Laptop 
Images are not scaled and uploaded as is.

Comment: HighDPI screens have problems, especially under Windows. Use Neon instead; it's the **current** release, after all.

Comment: Try changing your resolution, on my (nearly) 4k laptop display when I changed to 1920*1080 it scaled the icons properly.

Comment: Specifically the version of SWT used in Neon has had improvements in the handling of high DPI monitors.

Comment: Guys... Neon solved my problem for hDPI typos,.....thx for all the help extended.    Note: --- Neon Only works with JDK8 +